# File path wrong in PyCharm Python Console

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, pycharm

I'm a beginner of Python and I want to run a python3 script in PyCharm Python Console, but it raise an error below:

```
>>> /Users/mymac/Documents/Python/test.py
File "<input>", line1
/Users/mymac/Documents/Python/test.py
^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know what's wrong the file path is, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to call a function I just write in that .py file.

Comment: you have to import the file

Comment: try import test. If that doesn't work, navigate into the directory of your python script and then import test

Comment: I will very appreciate if you show me an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `execfile('/Users/mymac/Documents/Python/test.py')`. You are trying to run a python file like an executable. On top of that you are doing it in python interpreter.

Use python's execfile routine to call a file from interpreter or use `python test.py` to run it from the terminal.

Comment: It works! Thank u so much! My reputation is lower than 15 so I can't vote for you, sorry for that.

Comment: hey man! I found a new method and showed it below, have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be several things. Have you set your environmental correctly? You can test this by cmd: `python` it should return `Python 3.6.4` if that is your current version. If not then head over to [tutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_environment.htm) for how to correctly set up your path.

If that is correctly configured, then have you selected an interpreter in PyCharm. If not, File --> Settings --> Project: Network --> Project Interpreter. Select your python installation path.

Another thing to note is that I suspect you mean to use the terminal instead of the python console.

Then in PyCharms terminal section, `python test.py`.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, which raise an error like `NameError: name 'python3' is not defined`.

Comment: `python test.py` would work in that case. I have 2.7 also installed so in my case I needed to be explicit

Comment: It raise the error `NameError: name 'python' is not defined` again

Comment: Did you set your environmental Variables?

Comment: I think I didn't do that cause I’m not quite sure what the environmental variables are...

Answer (score 0):

I recognized that the answer I accepted ahead wasn't a perfect method, cause function `execfile` has been deleted in Python3, the alternative method is using `open` like:

`>>> with open ('/Users/mymac/Documents/Python/test.py', 'r') as f:
...      exec(f.read())
...`

Still thanks for guys who helped me!